# Password Protect the Applications Button

Tags: android, passwords, password-protection

How can I password protect the Applications button on my Home of my android phone (samsung galaxy s captivate).
I know there is password protect application out there with a list of application you need to add but I don't want that. I want to protect the whole access of the applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that blocking access to an application from the Home Screen isn't common practice, actually I think you can't even control this as it's part of the Android OS itself. After all, what's the point in blocking user access at the Home Screen since the user already has to unlock his phone in order to get there... usually trough a password.

A viable option would be to greet your users on a Login Activity and you'd have them identify themselves before they can access the actual Application functionality.

If you really want to start blocking users at the Home Screen, you're probably looking at creating your own ROM and Application. But then, no one will want to re-do their whole OS simply to run your application.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own home screen, one that prevents launching any applications unless the user authenticates.